# Gin-Rummy with different number of cards

Tags: variants, gin-rummy

Official Gin-Rummy is played with 10 cards.  I wish to implement in my game a shorter version with less cards.  What are the common/recommended number of cards?

- I guess that removing/adding multiplications of 3?  So 7,10,13,... should be nice.  Is that true?
- Any other rules modification when playing with less cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard [13 Card Rummy](https://www.rummyculture.com/blog/play-indian-13-card-rummy-games/) suggests you're OK to look to 13 as the basis of your pattern, yes.

For Gin, I'd say you have it right: hands should be 4 + 3*k cards for some positive integer k. 11 is conceivable, but strikes me as too confining.

When adjusting the hand size, you should also adjust the point limit barrier to knock. Since it's 10 points for a 10-card version, you might consider just keeping it the same as the number of cards.